# How do call vue component method in external js modul file outside vue components

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I do not know how do call Vue settings component method getStageLine inside external js modul.

My code sample for vue component isis:

```
const settings = {
        template: '#templateName',
        created:function(){
            this.getStageLine();

        },
        data:function(){
            return{
                test1:[],
                test:[],

            }
        },
        mounted(){

        },
        methods:{
            getStageLine:function(){
                axios.get(databaseConf.url + '/' + blaa)
                    .then(response => {

                        this.test1 = response.data

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
                axios.get(databaseConf.url + '/' + lol)
                    .then(response => {

                        this.test = response.data


                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            }
```

My code sample for external js modul:

```
var dash = (function(){
function addSomething(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data ,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and i want to call getStageLine method outside Vue component inside dash.addSomething(data) function.

I have tried $refs call then Vue.component.componentName.methods.methodName But that did not worked, so any suggestions how do call that function outside Vue, i tried other examples from stack but they did not work for me.

Comment: `settings` is not a vue component, it's just an object. You need to get a reference to the vue component then call `getStageLine` on it.

Comment: Show us the code you use to instantiate your VueJS component. As @Ikbel has said, you merely showed us the object, `settings`, that are used. What you can do is store the reference to the component in a variable, say `var myComponent = Vue.component('...', settings)` and then simply do `myComponent.getStageLine()`. See proof-of-concept example: https://jsfiddle.net/mhc2wpzv/1

Comment: Okey, but now if i need to call function from comonent greeting? i tried `vm.greeting.foo() `but that did not worked, can you provide me example?